# Ansible - create list out of with_items

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, jinja2, ansible-facts

How can I create a list out of `with_items`? I tried the following but it records only the last group ID instead of creating a list.

```
  - name: "Generate list"
    set_fact:
      my_new_list: "{{ [ item.group_id  ] }}" 
    with_items:
      - "{{ec2_info.instances[0].security_groups}}"
```

`ec2_info.instances[0].security_groups` has multiple group_id's.

```
                            "security_groups": [
                                {
                                    "group_id": "sg-0500c5b20f7c152b4",
                                    "group_name": "ManageIQ"
                                },
                                {
                                    "group_id": "sg-062178ea5fabaf350",
                                    "group_name": "launch-wizard-1"
                                }
                            ],
```

Comment: you want the list of all group_id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this playbook traps all the list:

```
 - name: "Generate list"
    set_fact:
      my_new_list: "{{ my_new_list|d([]) + [ item.group_id  ] }}" 
    with_items:
      - "{{ec2_info.instances[0].security_groups}}"
```

Comment: Can you explain what its doing? mainly the `my_new_list|d([]) +`

Comment: you record the content of each loop in a list..so at first loop d([]) initalizes my_new_list like an empty list..ist really common loop in ansible

Comment: Also is it possible to append one more security_group from another module register?

Comment: i dont see what you want to do..but its possible to add more list to a variable

Comment: if you have another problem..open a new question to avoid to pollute your question here

Comment: d([])  is equivalent to default([])